# Sequelize hooks, any way to get Express' user?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize and hooks (see here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/894). I'm trying to implement a kind of logging system, and would prefer to log on hooks instead of in my controllers. Anyone has any ideas on how I would be able to get my user from req.user into my hooks functions?

```
db.define('vehicle', {

    ...

}, {
    hooks: {
        beforeUpdate: function(values, cb){

            // Want to get my user in here.

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though its an old question, here is my answer. The problem is getting the current user from your request into the hook. These steps might enable you do get that:

1. Create a middleware with custom query functions

   ```
   req.context.findById = function(model){
     // Strip model from arguments
     Array.prototype.shift.apply(arguments);
     // Apply original function
     return model.findById.apply(model, arguments).then(function(result){
       result.context = {
         user: req.user
       }
       return result;
     });
   };
   ```
2. Do your put using `req.findById(model, id)` instead of `User.findById(id)`

   ```
   app.put("/api/user/:id", app.isAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
      // Here is the important part, user req.context.findById(model, id) instead of model.findById(id)
      req.context.findById(User, req.params.id).then(function(item){
         // item.context.user is now req.user
         if(!user){
            return next(new Error("User with id " + id + " not found"));
         }
         user.updateAttributes(req.body).then(function(user) {
            res.json(user);
         }).catch(next);
      }).catch(next);
   });
   ```
3. Use your hook, `instance.context.user` will be available

   ```
   User.addHook("afterUpdate", function(instance){
      if(instance.context && instance.context.user){
         console.log("A user was changed by " + instance.context.user.id);
      }
   });
   ```

You can find this procedure extracted into an express middleware here https://github.com/bkniffler/express-sequelize-user (I'm the creator).

Answer (score 6):

There is one simple solution that I am using in my project.

1) First when you create or update any model, pass your data in option argument like below:

```
model.create({},{ user: req.user}); // Or
model.update({},{ user: req.user});
```

2) Then, access your data inside the hook

```
User.addHook("afterUpdate", function(instance, options){
    console.log(' user data', options.user);
});
```

Comment: I was checking this solution. For your information,  I have written in TypeScript  and getting the error `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'authInfo' does not exist in type 'CreateOptions'.` Any suggestion?

Comment: I solved using [Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation)

```
declare module "sequelize" {
    interface CreateOptions {
        authInfo?: any;
    }

    interface UpdateOptions {
        authInfo?: any;
    }

    interface SaveOptions{
        authInfo?: any;
    }
    interface BulkCreateOptions{
        authInfo?: any;
    }
    
}

```

Answer (score 0):

If there's a one-to-many relationship between users and vehicles, and if the instance of Vehicle already associated with a user, then you can use vehicle.getUser().

```
...
beforeUpdate: function(vehicle,cb){
  vehicle.getUser()
  .then(function(user){
    console.log(user)
  })
}
```

Of if one of the attributes of vehicle is a uid.

```
beforeUpdate: function(vehicle,cb){
  User.find(vehicle.uid)
  .then(function(user){
    console.log(user)
  })
}
```

Otherwise this will have to be done in the controller. Is there a good reason for not handling this in the controller though? Creating a class method on Vehicle called logUser() that accepts req.user seems like the path of least resistance.

Comment: Accepted, even tough the question was asked *last year* and it doesn't really answer the question.